# how to stack landsat 8 layers correctly?

Tags: imagery

i downloaded a landsat8 satellite image from USGS, it was separated into 12 layers. So, what i  would like to do is to stack some of them. To do that, i am not sure which layer should be excluded from the stacking.
Any help?

Comment: please state what research you have already done on the subject. and what your use case is. There are many ways to view, use, and analyze landsat data. That is the entire reason for multiple layers.  http://landsat.usgs.gov/tools_project_documents.php

Comment: I think the information on this page: http://landsat.usgs.gov/L8_band_combos.php should help you understand which bands to use, depending on your need.

Answer (score 1):

A [MapBox link](http://www.mapbox.com/blog/processing-landsat-8/) should help you get started with combining Landsat 8 imagery using open source tools.

The first link under the heading entitled "first draft true color image" has a discussion about each band that comes in a bundle.